# How to use a function on each array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to run a function on each array within an array, however it only seems to run the iteration once, i dont get any error messages to help me figure out why?

its a basic credit card checker project

````
// An array of all the arrays above
const batch = [valid1, valid2, valid3, valid4, valid5, invalid1, invalid2, invalid3, invalid4, invalid5, mystery1, mystery2, mystery3, mystery4, mystery5];


// Add your functions below:
const validateCred = (arr) =>{
  let totalSum = 0
  let newArr = arr.slice(0);
  let lastDigit = newArr.pop()
  newArr = newArr.reverse()
  for(i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++){
    if (i % 2 === 0){
      let doubled = newArr[i] * 2
      if (doubled > 9){
        doubled -= 9
      }
      totalSum += doubled
    } else {
      totalSum += newArr[i]
    }
  }

  if((totalSum + lastDigit) % 10 === 0){
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
};

const findInvalidCards = (arrBatch) =>{
  let invalidCred = []
  for(i = 0; i<arrBatch.length; i++){
    console.log(validateCred(arrBatch[i]))
  }
};

findInvalidCards(batch);```
````

Comment: Please post the the proper input example for batch. It will help to debug faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `i` as a global variable in both for-loops. That could be the problem.

Try replacing `for(i = 0;` with `for(let i = 0;` both in `validateCred` and `findInvalidCards`

Comment: This worked perfectly, could you explain a little as to how it was causing it to exit after one run, just so i can get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i` is not a local variable. The inner function updates `i` in the global scope, so the outer function exits after only one run.

Change `for (i = 0...` to `for (var i = 0` and it should run.

Comment: This worked perfectly, could you explain a little as to how it was causing it to exit after one run, just so i can get my head around it.

Comment: @Jperkins98 In Javascript, if you use `const`, `let`, or `var`, it creates a variable which can only be accessed by that function or any functions in "scope." If you forget to declare the variable, Javascript will automatically create the variable and assign it to the global (i.e., window) context.

This means `validateCred` is changing the *global* value of i to 8. When `findInvalidCards` runs checks the loop condition `i<arrBatch.length`, it evaluates to true after the first run. 

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp.

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter will work.

Looks like you are doing a `Luhn` check on each number, should be easy to transpose that code onto this model.

```js
const sampleArray = [0,1,2,0,6,0,4,5,8];

const validNum = (num) => num > 0;

const validNumbers = sampleArray.filter(n => validNum(n));

console.log(validNumbers);
```

Comment: I agree this is the best solution, but this level of Javascript is probably beyond the poster's expertise.

Comment: Yes, I should have supplied a better description of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, and assuming your other functions are correct, you can do something like below:

```
const findInvalidCards = (arrBatch) =>{
    let invalidCred = []
    for(let i = 0; i<arrBatch.length; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j<arrBatch[i].length; j++){
            if( !validateCred(arrBatch[i][j]) ) {  // if invalid then push to arary
                invalidCred.push(arrBatch[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return invalidCred;  // return array of invalid cards
};

findInvalidCards(batch);
```